# Как вызвать аяксом функцию внутри РНР-класса с запрещённым прямым доступом

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Есть РНР-файл с классом и функцией внутри класса, который подключается к файлу с главным классом:

```
if(defined('VERSION'))
    define('version', VERSION);
    defined('version') OR die('Direct access is forbidden!');

class addClass extends mainClass {
    private function some_method() {
        return 'Result';
    }
}
```

И есть Аякс-запрос на чистом Джаваскрипте:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "filter=true";
request.open('POST', '/addclass.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onload = function(data) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
request.send(params);
```

**Вопрос**: как получить аяксом ответ функции `some_method()` ?

Если вставить

```
if($_REQUEST['filter'] == true) {
   echo addClass::some_method();
}
```

в самом начале файла *addclass.php* еще перед `class addClass {}` (при этом не важно перед `if(defined('VERSION'))` или после), тогда в консоле получаю ошибку

> POST http://mydomain.com/addclass.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

А если вставить эти строки после `class addClass {}` тогда в качестве аякс-ответа получаю только

> Direct access is forbidden!

Comment: `if(defined('VERSION'))` - вы используете какой-то фрэймворк? Если хотите его обойти, выбросьте if и поставьте ваш код после объявления класса

Comment: Это не фреймворк, это простой способ защиты файла **addclass.php** от прямого доступа. В главном файле при этом стоит `define('version', '1.0');`

Comment: Вы получаете 500 потому, что вызываете метод класса до его объявления. А вторая ошибка говорит о том, что *главный файл* не выполнялся до addclass.php.

Comment: и метод some_method приватный, его нникак нельзя вызвать напрямую, также он не статический, чтобы вызывать его через два двоеточия.

Comment: @stckvrw что еще за защита от прямого доступа? что вы подразумеваете вод этим вашим "прямым доступом"? это не защита, это костыль какой-то бесполезный в принципе.

Comment: @teran почему костыль, define'ы ведь как раз используют для защиты от прямого доступа. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408344/preventing-direct-access-is-it-possible-to-spoof-a-php-define#comment30477944_20408344) даже написали что "it's how all big projects do it".

Comment: вы там вопрос то читали? там человек спрашивает, как отключить выполнение `header.php` при прямом запросе через `site.com/header.php`. у вас же вопрос не про это совсем

Comment: Да, у меня вопрос о другом. Но здесь в комментах мы говорим не о моем вопросе, а о способе как запретить прямой доступ к файлу именно при вводе в адресную строку `site.com/file.php` и там в комменте (я дал ссылку на коммент) пишут что `define()` это не костыль, а способ, который используют большие проекты

Comment: оставив в вэбруте только `index.php` вы вообще исключите все подобные вопросы, либо запретив в хтаксессе доступ к другим пхп файлам.